# Open Link When Clicked on CardView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My App Uses AsyncTask to fetch data from a WebAPI and displays them in a Recycler View.

What I intend to do is open the corresponding link when clicked on a card view in the browser installed on phone.

I tried all the solutions mentioned but my App always seems to crash.

If I use sendBroadcast instead it doesn't do anything.

My Code for the Recycler View Adapter :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final News news = listnews.get(position);

    holder.tvTitle.setText(news.getTitle());
    holder.tvDesc.setText(news.getDescription());

    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(news.getUrlToImage()).into(holder.ivNews);
    holder.newsLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(news.getUrl()));
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

The App works fine and loads all the news items but when I click on a news item it crashes with the stopped responding message.

Comment: post error log and full code of RecyclerView Adapter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add this line `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

like below :-

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(news.getUrl()));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: wow, it worked, Thank you.
can you please explain what that line of code does please.

Comment: It will start a new activity with matching intent filter, in a new task only if
that corresponding task is not in memory now. For more detail click [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#addFlags(int))